# PHP + large CSV file + Shell

Tags: php, shell, csv, exec

My hosting is shared, their rule is at most `30` the `set_time_limit`, I already tried in several ways changing in `cpanel` or `.htaccess` I have many lines in different files to save.

Currently I am cutting the contents of the files in several files so as not to exceed the time:

```
$lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/lines1.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    //here is some code for save you content line
}
```

But, someone told me to use the code:

```
exec("php csv_import.php > /dev/null &");
```

This would run only a single file `.csv` in the background instead of multiple files , without having problems with exceeding time limit

It is the first time I see about shell and php, and I have doubts on how to work

I have to create a file `csv_import.php`with the normal php code? But how do I run this in the shell of my server?

Comment: and what is the question, exactly?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I would just like to do the same as the first example of the code in shell code and understand how to do this within my php function

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I edited my question, please see

Answer (score 1):

If your host allow you to change the value you can define an different time limit on the php file.

```
<?php

$minutes = 30 ; // just for easy manage
$runfor =$minutes * 60;
set_time_limit ( $runfor );

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my hosting is shared, their rule is at most 30 the `set_time_limit`, I already tried in several ways changing in `cpanel` or `.htaccess`

Comment: did you try ni_set('max_execution_time', 300);at the top of your php file ?